# how to install libmysqld-dev on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, gearman

When I enter command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev
```

I have this message:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libmysqld-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient-dev (>= 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had error because I was used the MariaDB. 1st step - Remove MariaDB; 2nd -  Install MySQL; Thats all =)

Answer (score 1):

I would say, try the solution(s) from the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies/) (credits go to Amith KK, of course), of which this one is the easiest:

> One of the most basic fixes to resolve dependencies problems is to run:
>
> `sudo apt-get -f install`
>
> The -f hare stands for “fix broken”. Apt will attempt to correct broken dependencies. If  you manually installed a package that had unmet dependencies, apt-get will install those dependencies, if possible, otherwise it may simply remove the package that you installed in order to resolve the problem.
>
> Then run:
>
> `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
>
> Then run this again:
>
> `sudo apt-get -f install`
>
> If the output is:
>
> `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.`
>
> That means it failed.

Comment: I had error because I was used the MariaDB. 1st step - Remove MariaDB; 2nd -  Install MySQL; Thats all =)